# PHP code does not start when the page is loaded

Tags: php

I made the code below to show the files that were inserted by the user, however it only shows the files after having attached a file, however I wanted it to show when loading the page, for the user to see what files he has already uploaded. Here is the code I used to upload the file:

```
<center><p class="text-success" style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 100px;">
  <?php
  session_start();
  require_once('conecta.php');
  $email = $_SESSION['email'];
  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $arq = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    $dataup = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $dataup;

    $arq = str_replace(" ", "_", $arq);
    $arq = str_replace("ç", "c", $arq);

    if (file_exists("uploads/".$arq)) {
      $a = 1;

      while (file_exists("uploads/[".$a."]".$arq)) {
        $a++;
      }

      $arq = "[".$a."]".$arq;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$arq)) {
      $objDb = new db();
      $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
      $sql = "insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('".  $email."', '".$arq."')";
      if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo 'Plano de aula 1 enviado com sucesso!';
      } else {
        echo (mysqli_error($link));
        echo 'Erro ao enviar o plano de aula!';
      }

    } else {
      echo "Nenhum arquivo selecionado!";
    }

  }
  ?>
</p></center>
```

Here is the code to show the file on the page:

```
<?php
       session_start();
       require_once('conecta.php');
       $pasta = "uploads/";
       $consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE email_vol = '$email'");
        while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            echo "<a href=\"" . $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"] . "\">" . $resultado["nomearq"] . "</a><br />";
        } 
?>
```

Can someone give me a hand? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: whats the file name?

Comment: @unreleased the files name is saved in the variable ***$arq*** by ***$arq = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];***

Comment: When loading which page? The second script should show all the files in the database.

Comment: Are you talking about the page with the `<form>` that submits to the first script? It should have code like you have in the second script.

Comment: @Barmar When loading the page to upload the files, with the <form>. It shows all the files, but only if a add another file, if I just load the page the script doesn't execute.

Comment: Is the code to show the list inside `if(isset($_POST['enviar']))`? It shouldn't be, since that's only set when you submit the form.

Comment: @Barmar It isn't inside, but it is in the same php page, can this be the problem?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Barmar Do you know if ***required_once*** only set when you submit the form?

Comment: No, it runs all the time. Nothing in PHP is specific to submitting a form, unless you do explicit checks for variables like `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: @Barman Man, somethng weard is happen, i just put a simple echo at the code to show the email and it works just fine, only the party with the mysqli doesn't work. It just run the query if i submit